# Dynamic text to be sent using MIMEMultipart and SES service in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mime, amazon-ses, multipart

I am using lambda to send a raw message from SES.

```
def send_email_method(p1, p2):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg["Subject"] = "Test123"
    msg["From"] = "abc@gmail.com"
    msg["To"] = "xyz@gmail.com"

    
    body = MIMEText("Find list of activity. Part 1="+ p1 +"Part 2=" + p2, "html") /** Here according to 3 conditions below data should be sent**/
    msg.attach(body)
        
    ses_client = boto3.client("ses", region_name="us-west-1")
    response = ses_client.send_raw_email(
        Source="abc@gmail.com",
        Destinations=["xyz@gmail.com"],
        RawMessage={"Data": msg.as_string()}
    )
    return

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    p1=os.environ['p1']
    p2=os.environ['p2']
    send_email_method(p1, p2)
```

The p1 and p2 environment vars can have following values :-

1. **p1**='sketch',  **p2**='draw'---- In this case both **p1 & p2** should be mentioned in mail
2. **p1**='',  **p2**='draw'---- In this case only **p2** should be mentioned in mail as p1 is empty
3. **p1**='sketch',  **p2**=''----In this case only **p1** should be mentioned in mail as p2 is empty

How can the above 3 conditions be achieved in the above code keeping in mind that these p1 & p2 can extend to p3,p4 and p5 as well??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method would be to use some `if` statements to construct your message.

However, since the number of variables could increase in future, I'd recommend changing the program to **pass a dictionary** to the `send_email_method()` function, which will allow any number of inputs. The function could then loop through the dictionary and construct the string, something like:

```
values = {1: "sketch", 2: "draw", 3:"erase", 4:"rotate"}

message = ""

for value in values:
  message += f" Part {value}={values[value]}"
```